# Adjusting a fluid container in a Vuetify layout

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using **Vuetify** as the front end framework for a **VueJS** application I am developing, however I am having an issue adjusting the fluid container that holds the main content to underlay the footer. When the content expands past the height of the page, the footer overlays the content. How can I adjust the main content container so that it takes the height of the footer into consideration when displaying the table content?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
                <v-app-bar color="primary white--text" light app clipped-left clipped-right fixed>
            <v-toolbar-title class="ml-0 pl-3">
              <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="navMenu = !navMenu" color="white"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
              <span class="hidden-sm-and-down">Memory Infuser</span>
            </v-toolbar-title>

            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          </v-app-bar>
    
          <v-main>
            <v-container fluid class="pt-0">
                <v-row class="pr-2 pl-2">
                        <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-data-table
                      :headers="headers"
                      :items="desserts"
                      :items-per-page="20"
                      class="elevation-1"
                    ></v-data-table>  
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
          </v-main>
    
          <v-footer app light color="primary white--text">
                <v-card tile flat class="text-center" color="primary" width="100%">
                    <v-card-text class="white--text">
                              Footer Text
                    </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
          </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/deftonez4me/pen/WNoyrGY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give the `v-footer` component an `absolute` prop, and also if you still have issues in responsive view of the page you should set the `height` prop for the `v-footer` component like this:

```
<v-footer app light absolute :height="80" color="primary white--text">
   ...
</v-footer>
```

Comment: Setting a height fixed the problem, however I want to keep the footer fixed to the bottom, so it did not need the absolute property.